# play against a computer, then analyze it software.

Tags: learning, software

this is a simple question, thanks in advance for your answers!

I am looking for a free software which allows me to

1) play chess against a computer

2) analyze the game I had (did i screw up at any point, did i miss something obvious)

3) is free!

Thank you

Comment: Download SCID and Stockfish6.  I run it on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I use Playchess, Stock Fish and Chessbase. 
However, I would recommend analyzing manually yourself before letting the computer analyze the game. That way you can improve so much!

Comment: I agree! You learn a lot by seeing your own mistakes. Although sometimes computer analyze can just do the same. Sometimes you don't see it until the computer analyze tells you to. For instance, I was playing chess with somebody and he made a blunder. The computer analyze said he could check-mate me (which he didn't) and because the computer analyze said that, he saw how he could check-mate me.

Answer (score 0):

As Tony Ennis points out in his comment you can download [SCID](http://scid.sourceforge.net/) and Stockfish 6 for free and use them to play and analyse your games.

There are also websites that allow you do it, for instance [Chess24](https://chess24.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using http://en.lichess.org/paste for analysis, it is very fast and helpful and gives you a human like analysis.